# iOS App Development: Background Image on entire screen including the top time row

Tags: ios, ios13, ios14

I am looking for documentation on how to set a background image on specific parts of the app.

More specifically:

I have not yet found a way how to add a background image that covers the entire screen ***including*** the top time and battery row in iOS.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you've tried so far, and in which situation (what kind of view) you need this.
Let's take a regular `UIViewController` without `UINavigationBar` as example.
Here you add a `UIImageView`, and apply the following constraints:

- Align trailing to **superview**
- Align leading to **superview**
- Bottom space to **superview**
- Top space to **superview**

By constraining all edges to the superview (instead of the safe-area), it should fill up every part of the screen.

Set an appropiate image and content mode to the right setting.

[image: full-screen background image]

Answer (score 0):

Answering your specific qn,

In order to have a background image that extends to complete screen, you should make `status bar` and `navigation bar` (of course, if you VC is embedded in `Navigation Controller`) **transparent**.

For that, use `UIImageView`, set the image you want;
Then in the `viewDidLoad()` method of your VC, write the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        
    }
```

Now, you should be able to see that the background image covers the entire screen including the status bar.

Let me know if it worked.